# Store array of SwiftUI views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'd like to store an array of SwiftUI views, passed through in a SwiftUI-style initialiser. These views won't necessarily all be of the same type.

I have this at the moment, which works for views of the same type:

```swift
struct ViewHolder<Content: View> {
    var content: () -> Content
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(@ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
    }
}

struct ViewDisplayer<Content: View>: View {
    
    var views: [ViewHolder<Content>]
    
    init(@ArrayBuilder<ViewHolder<Content>> content: () -> [ViewHolder<Content>]) {
        self.views = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(views, id: \.id) {view in
            view.content()
        }
    }
    
}
    
@resultBuilder
public class ArrayBuilder<Element> {
    public static func buildBlock(_ elements: Element...) -> [Element] {
        return elements
    }
}
```

This can be used like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewDisplayer {
            ViewHolder {
                Text("Hi")
            }
            ViewHolder {
                Text("Hi")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It breaks however, if the not all the ViewHolders have the same content:

```
ViewHolder {
    Text("Hi")
}
ViewHolder { //Cannot convert value of type 'ViewHolder<Button<Text>>' to expected argument type 'ViewHolder<Text>'
    Button("") {
            
    }
}
```

I'd prefer to not have to wrap everything in `AnyView(...)`, any ideas?

Comment: If you want to store an array of non-homogenous `View`s, `AnyView` is your only choice. However, I'd explore the option of a different architectural approach anyway, since I believe (can't prove with documentation) that storing `View`s like this is an anti-pattern in SwiftUI. I would, for instance, opt for storing a model that represents the different types of views (an `enum` with associated values perhaps) and render the view hierarchy based on that.

Comment: What is the possible use case to need to do this?

Comment: It has nothing actually with SwiftUI - it is swift static typing, `ViewHolder<Text> != ViewHodler<Button>` the same as `Int != String`. You don't try to add `String` to `Array<Int>`, right? Why do you try that to do with above types? Just rethink design to avoid using array for such cases (or use `AnyView` as single type).

Comment: Would a Group do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you overcomplicated your code.

First of all, your example is definitely incomplete, as in your example your topmost view is a ForEach, which is unlikely. (Replace `VStack` in my example with whatever topmost container View you have.)

But other than that, you really should not care about the exact type of your views, and just create a single `ViewBuilder` like this:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct VHolder<T: View>: View {
    var content: T
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            content
        }
    }
}

struct VHolder_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VHolder {
            Text("Hi")
            Button("Hi", action: { })
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to embed your ViewHolders in the "ViewDisplayer", it is just another layer that should be the same (unless it has a different container view - let's say `HStack`):

```
struct HHolder<T: View>: View {
    var content: T
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> T) {
        self.content = content()
    }

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            content
        }
    }
}

struct HHolder_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HHolder {
            VHolder {
                Text("Hi")
                Button("Hi", action: { })
            }

            VHolder {
                Text("Not Hi")
                Button("Not Hi", action: { })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is tested and works on XCode 12.5. You can see I could add `Button` and `Text` views in the same closure.

Comment: Making a comment about the legitimacy of the question doesn't answer the guy's question.